# ActionBarSherlock giving errors

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

"The type android.support.v4.app Fragment cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files."

Imported Wallpaper Manager (I want to implement ActionBarSherlock in it) in Eclipse,

Imported ActionBarSherlock latest version library folder in Eclipse,

Set that library folder as library for using with other projects from ACS's Properties > Android,

Set ActionBarSherlock as library for Wallpaper Manager from WM's Properties > Android..

Answer (score 1):

Are you copying the jar as well as linking to it? In eclipse, that option is not checked by default.

Comment: Where to copy the jar files?

Comment: Go to Project > Properties > Java Build Path, amd make sure that the ABS jar is checked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that you dont have another android.support.v4.app library in your libs folder
2. Try cleaning your project

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your support library is of the same version as the one you are referencing in your project.